# Are RavenDB bundles still published via NuGet?

Tags: ravendb

I have a unit test project with references to Raven.Client.Embedded and Raven.Database v2.0.3, which were added via NuGet. I was looking to add the RavenDB Versioning bundle, also via NuGet, but the current Versioning package references Raven.Database v1.0.992.

Is there a new way to include bundles into an embedded document store, or is NuGet still the right way to go? And if it's still NuGet, can I help in some way to get the published package updated in the NuGet Gallery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The versioning bundle is now part of the RavenDB core, and doesn't require a separate bundle.